# How to check for transaction integrity for 2 different smart contracts?

Tags: solidity, transactions, multicall

Let's say I have smart contract A and smart contract B. I want to transfer the ownership of smart contract B to another account **ONLY IF** a transaction against smart contract A has been successful.

I understand I have to build both `Tx-A` and `Tx-B` and send them to the chain as part of the same transaction.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to write a third contract, smart contract C, that tries to execute Tx-A and then, if that is successful, run Tx-B.

```
import {contractA} from "<path to contract A>";
import {contractB} from "<path to contract B>";
contract C {
    function execute() external {
        contractA A = contractA(<address of A>);
    
        bool success = A.functionYouWantToCall();

        require(success, "functionYouWantToCall not successful");

        contractB B = contractB(<address of B>);

        B.transferOwnership(<new address>);
    }

}
```

Now you can run `C.execute()` to achieve your goal.

Instead of writing your own contract, there may already be a contract on chain that lets you assemble function calls without having to write your own contract.  For instance, many DEXs have a router that allows for "[multicalls](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/afb20119b33072da041c97ea717d3ce4417b5e01/contracts/utils/Multicall.sol)".  See the test example which shows two functions being called in one transaction: https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/a28aafdc85a592776544f7978c6b1a462d28ede2/test/utils/Multicall.test.js#L45-L51

A list of multicall contract addresses by chain is at https://www.multicall3.com/deployments